# Magento 2.2 html tags display on frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend

I created custom category attribute like full description and just copy layout and template from category description. But all text i put in my custom full description display with html tags
[image: full description display with html tags]

[image: in admin page]

Answer (score 1):

**Try following code:**

> Block file of your custom module:

```
<?php

namespace [VendoreName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Content;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Content extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    protected $_filterProvider;

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCmsFilterContent($value='')
    {
        $html = $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($value);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

> Template file of your custom module:

```
<div>
    <?php $content = 'Content to be filtered' ?>
    <?php $html = $block->getCmsFilterContent($content);  ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo $html ?>
    </p>
</div>
```